# Angular 2: specify either statically analyzable bootstrap code or pass in an entrymodule to the plugins options

Tags: angular

I am currently attempting to introduce AOT compilation to my Angular2 project.

After following all of the steps set out in https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler, I received the error `specify either statically analyzable bootstrap code or pass in an entrymodule to the plugins options` after running the command `ng build --aot`.

#### versions

1. @angular/cli@1.2.4
2. typscript@2.4.2
3. node@6.9.4

#### main.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowser }    from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppModuleNgFactory } from '../aot/src/app/app.module.ngfactory';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
};

platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
```

Comment: Perhaps a good idea is to show your actual bootstrap code :)

Comment: You do not need to change your `main.ts` Angular-cli will do it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently with @angular/cli none of the steps set out in  https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler are needed and the `main.ts` file can stay the same. This is because AOT compilation is now built into the angular cli and runs as default on `ng build --prod`.

After reverting my `main.ts` file back to:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/modules/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

I received a new error `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory'` after reading the issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18380 the issue was solved by updating my @angular/cli version to 1.2.6. Everything is now working fine.